# Why does my menu jump the second time I try and drag it to a new item?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, pi

I've made a rotating menu.

To select an item you rotate the menu by clicking and dragging.

http://codepen.io/PaulBunker/pen/ZGgxvY

```
var dragging = false;
var links = $('.menu a');
var radius = 520;
var degree = 0.262;
var angle = 0.79;
var orgX;
var orgY;
var offset = $('.menu').offset();
var newangle;
var origradians;

function setItems(angle) {
    var internalangle = angle;
    links.each(function() {

        var y = Math.round(radius * Math.cos(internalangle));
        var x = Math.round(radius * Math.sin(internalangle));

        $(this).css({
            left: x + 'px',
            top: 0-y + 'px',
            display:'block',
        });

        $(this).addClass(y);


        if (y < 10 & x > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        if ( y < -10 || y > 0) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }


        internalangle += degree;

    });
}


$(function() {

    $(document).mousedown(function(evt) {
        orgX = evt.pageX - offset.left;
        orgY = evt.pageY - offset.top;
        orgradians = Math.atan2(orgX, orgY);
        dragging = true;
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        dragging = false;
        angle = newangle;
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(evt) {
        if (dragging) {

            var x = evt.pageX - offset.left;
            var y = evt.pageY - offset.top;
            var radians = Math.atan2(y, x);


            newangle =  (orgradians + radians) - angle;
            console.log (orgradians , radians, angle, newangle);

            setItems(newangle);
            console.log(newangle);
        }
    });

    setItems(angle);

});
```

My problem is after the first drag to select an item.

At the beginning of the second drag the menu jumps into the wrong position.

on 'mouseup' I save the 'newangle' variable and override the 'angle variable'.

I suspect there is an error somewhere in the line

```
newangle =  (orgradians + radians) - angle;
```

I've been tearing my hair out to try and get this to work!

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

-Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use trigonometry on mouse move and just use it once when the radius of the circle is defined it'll fix the issue:

1. Work out the rotation speed based on the radius of the circle:

   ```
   var rotationSpeed = Math.atan(1/radius);
   ```
2. Use the rotation speed and the difference in the Y position of the cursor on mouse move:

   ```
   var newangle = lastangle - (difY*rotationSpeed);
   ```

http://codepen.io/stevenarcher/pen/yNmRyP

```
var dragging = false;
var links = $('.menu a');
var radius = 520;
var degree = 0.262;
var lastY;
var offset = $('.menu').offset();
var lastangle = 0;
var rotationSpeed = Math.atan(1/radius);


function setItems(internalangle) {
    links.each(function() {

        var y = Math.round(radius * Math.cos(internalangle));
        var x = Math.round(radius * Math.sin(internalangle));

        $(this).css({
            left: x + 'px',
            top: 0 - y + 'px',
            display:'block',
        });

        $(this).addClass(y);

        if (y < 10) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        if ( y < -10 || y > 0) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        internalangle += degree;

    });
}



$(document).mousedown(function(evt) {
    lastY = evt.pageY - offset.top;
    dragging = true;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(evt) {
    dragging = false;
});

$(document).mousemove(function(evt) {

    if (dragging) {    
        var y = evt.pageY - offset.top;
        var difY = lastY - y;
        lastY = y;
        var newangle = lastangle - (difY*rotationSpeed);
        setItems(newangle);
        lastangle = newangle;
    }
});

setItems(0);
```